# Series Reduction

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm not too familiar with sequences and series and I would like to show

$ n = \dfrac{n}{2^{n-1}}(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-2} 2^i + 1) $

I've been playing around with it on paper and tried expanding and rearranging but I'm sure there's some property I'm not familiar with that I could exploit.

If someone could walk me through some intuitive steps, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Divide both sides by $\dfrac{n}{2^{n-1}}$ and you get something easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* $1+1 = 2$, $\ 2+2=2^2$, $\ 2^2+2^2=2^3$, $\ \ldots$, $\ 2^{n-2}+2^{n-2}=2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Ah, seeing it this way makes sense; at least I was on the right track. :) Thanks.